# Distinguish digits from alphabet and create new column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

The dataframe looks like this:
`df`:

```
    item_id value 
0   101002  1.008665
1   101004  2.025818
2   101005  0.530516
3   101007  0.732918
4   101010  1.787264
... ... ...
621 ZB005   3.464102
622 ZB007   2.345208
623 ZB008   3.464102
624 ZBD002  2.592055
625 ZBD005  2.373321
```

I would like to create a new column `newcol` based on the first element/letter of column `item_id` :
If the first letter of `item_id` is alphabet , return "alphabet "; if the first letter is number, return "number".

Expected output:

```
    item_id value     newcol
0   101002  1.008665  number
1   101004  2.025818  number 
2   101005  0.530516  number
3   101007  0.732918  number
4   101010  1.787264  number
... ... ...
621 ZB005   3.464102  alphabet 
622 ZB007   2.345208  alphabet 
623 ZB008   3.464102  alphabet 
624 ZBD002  2.592055  alphabet 
625 ZBD005  2.373321  alphabet
```

I tried:

```
df['new_component'] = [lambda x: 'alphabet' if x.isalpha() else 'number' for x in df.item_id]
```

which returned

```
    item_id value       new_component
0   101002  1.008665    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000002663B04E948>
1   101004  2.025818    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000002663B04E828>
2   101005  0.530516    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000002663B04EAF8>
3   101007  0.732918    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000002663B04EB88>
4   101010  1.787264    <function <listcomp>.<lambda> at 0x000002663B04EC18>
... ... ...
```

What's wrong in the code? Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the column with default value `'alphabet'` first and change the ones with numbers:

```
df['newcol'] = 'alphabet'
df.loc[df.item_id.str[0].str.isdigit(),'newcol'] = 'number'
```

If you prefer to do it the way you tried, this is how to do it:

```
df['newcol'] = ['number' if x[0].isdigit() else 'alphabet' for x in df.item_id]
```

or equivalently:

```
df['newcol'] = ['alphabet' if x[0].isalpha() else 'number' for x in df.item_id]
```

output:

```
    item_id     value    newcol
0    101002  1.008665    number
1    101004  2.025818    number
2    101005  0.530516    number
3    101007  0.732918    number
4    101010  1.787264    number
621   ZB005  3.464102  alphabet
622   ZB007  2.345208  alphabet
623   ZB008  3.464102  alphabet
624  ZBD002  2.592055  alphabet
625  ZBD005  2.373321  alphabet
```

Comment: Hi Ehsan, thanks for the awesome answer. Just some additional questions if you don't mind answering: Why is lambda not needed here? When is the right time to use it?

Comment: @nilsinelabore You are welcome. lambda is basically a function (inline) and is callable. You are trying to assign to a pandas series on the left hand side `df['newel']`, therefore your right hand side need to be of similar structure. What your code does, is instead of having a function that is called on the members of a list, it creates a list whose member is a function (a.k.a lambda) itself. Lambda has many applications and I cannot summarize it in a sentence, however, try to think of it as a function.

Answer (score 1):

In the list comprehension, you are creating a list of lambda functions.

All you need is to first define the lambda function outside the list

```
y=lambda x, ...
```

Then, call it in the list comprehension.